# Webshim polyfiller not working on IE9 when the page is embedded inside the iframe

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, modernizr, polyfills

I am using **Webshim polyfiller** to parse HTML 5 form elements on IE7+. It works great in IE7 and IE8 but throwing **“Unspecified error” on IE9 when the page is called inside the iframe.**

When the HTML page (the page loaded with polyfiller.js) is embedded inside the iframe IE9 throws “Unspecified error” and the polyfills for input field types like number, range and placeholder attribute are not working. When the url of the page is access directly it all works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does IE9 need the same polyfill?

You might try adding the polyfill using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE9]><script src="/your-polyfill.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Actually I am using this polyfill for HTML5 form elements. IE9 still doesn't support fully HTML5 input types and properties. though I need to use this polyfill